# Minimum JDK & JRE to be used with JAX-WS 2.2.x

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, compatibility

I am using JAX-WS wsimport to generate stubs to call Web Services. I need JAX-WS 2.2 or above - which is default only with JDK/JRE 7. What is the minimum JRE/JDK JAX-WS 2.2 can be used against? Can it be used with JRE5. Can it it be used with JRE6. The JAX-WS documentation describes how to use JAX-WS 2.2.x with JDK 6 - https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.7/docs/ch02.html#running-on-top-of-jdk-6

However, this documentation seems to be for web services on the server side. I couldn't find anything clear in the documentation about whether it can be used for client stubs with JRE 6 (i.e. generation client stubs with JAX-WS 2.2.x & then running them against JRE 6).

Is this fully supported? Any caveats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) is the way to go for both client and server.

This mechanism also applies to Java 5 but I don't expect there was much testing of JAX-WS 2.2 on it.